# Editext hide behind the keyboard when it appear

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to move only edittext when keyboard will appear.
Here is my XML codes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".chat.MultipleMediaActivity">
    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/multiple_media_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />
    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        layout="@layout/multiple_media_custom_toolbar" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@drawable/multimedia_edittext_bg_ca"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/emoj_button"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
                android:src="@drawable/main_emoj_ca"
                android:tag="emoji" />
            <com.vanniktech.emoji.EmojiEditText
                android:id="@+id/multiple_media_text_message"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@color/AppTrasColor"
                android:hint="@string/write_message_ca"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
                android:maxLines="4"
                android:minHeight="50dp"
                android:textColor="@color/AppFirstTextColorDark"
                android:textColorHint="@color/AppDullTextColor"
                android:textSize="@dimen/Text17"
                tools:ignore="LabelFor"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/multiple_media_preview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp">

        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What I have tried
in manifest

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

When edittext getting focus, edittext stay below the keyboard,
I want to setup like
Bottom line of edittext and Top line of keyboard will be the same. It means edittext will always stay above the keyboard when it appear.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  Android has 3 modes for when the keyboard appears:

adjustNone-  do nothing.  The keyboard will appear over the app as it is.  This is almost never used

adjustResize-  the keyboard is asked for its height, and the app is fit into the remaining screen.  This will cause elements to be relaid out.

adjustPan-  the app will scroll such that the cursor is on screen.  If this is a multiline edit box, it promises that the line with the cursor will be shown.  Other lines below it may or may not be, depending on where on the screen that cursor is.

There is no mode for moving the entire edit text above the keyboard.

Comment: i think it will possible, in whatsapp open gallery , media preview activity edittext  stay above the keyboard

Comment: @VoraRavi If the edit text is at the bottom, then you can do it with adjustResize.  But in the general case its impossible.